# How to decide which Probability distribution to use on a specific problem?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability

I need some guidance. Which probability distribution I can use to understand the number of orders one person can handle in a company? It's like each person has orders which takes minimum of 50 days to complete and no limit is there on how many one can handle.

So, I was thinking to check out a way to limit the number of orders one can handle which will not result into overburdening of resources.  Can anyone help me how can I solve this? I thought of "poisson distribution" but I want some expert guidance.

Comment: Are you interested in the number of orders a person can complete in a specific time frame or are you simply interested in how long it takes to complete an order?

Comment: Ordinarily, one collects data in order to understand a situation like this.  Do you have any data?

Comment: @StatsStudent i am looking for the first option.

Answer (score 0):

The type of analysis you run may matter, and it's not clear what exactly you will use. But as generic advice it seems sensible to start with an approach that assumes either poisson or normal error distribution, run your analysis then test to see if the error structure fits your selected distribution. If it does then great, if not try other distributions or a non parametric alternative.